# Making custom world map in Mapbox

Tags: shapefile, mapbox, mapbox-studio, tableau

I have .shp and .csv files for polygons that I have extracted from the georeferenced version of the pangea supercontinent. Link to the image which I have started from: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-j6ZGqXskUm8/UDem8twbzaI/AAAAAAAACfY/fs-E3_PR-N8/s1600/pangea_politik.jpg

In mapbox: I am trying to use these files to make an underlying custom map, to be further used in Tableau. When I uploaded the .shp file as a tileset, it was saved as a vector layer. I imported it into the 'style', and tried to 'publish' it. The published map could not link with the data that I used in Tableau, and the heatmap that I published used the country shapefiles in the current day, and not the pangea ones that I made.

I want to finally produce a heatmap of users on the pangea map. Can somebody help me out?